# Откол круглого куска от круглого объекта

Tags: unity3d

Допустим у меня есть круглый объект. Планета или яблоко...

И я хочу, чтобы от него во время игры "отстрелили", "отгрызли" или любым другим способом отделили круглый (или овальный) кусок. Выглядеть это должно как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественно с физикой.

Такое может происходить много раз и, теоретически, отстрелена может быть даже часть уже отстреленного куска. Как такое можно реализовать?

Вот нашел такую иллюстрацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ¿А в чем собственно затруднение? Найти пересечение двух эллипсов и построить два новых меша по нему вроде как элементарная задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай новый `Texture2d` тех-же размеров. Перенеси имеющуюся текстуру. В квадрате шириной `2*blowRadius` с центров в точке хита(придется посчитать) по дистанции поменяй альфу пиксели на `0`. Отдельно обработай края что-бы не было резкого алайзинга.

Создай новый спрайт из этой текстуры. `PolygonCollider2D` останется старый, для перещёта удали компонент и добавь заново.

Не забывай уничтожать старые сгенерированные текстуры при генерации новых или уничтожении объекта `Destroy(texture)`, что бы не засерать память.

Comment: Все прекрасно работает. Центр оказывается не там где мне надо, потому что вот такой я хороший математик, но про попиксельную работу с текстурой я не догадался.

Comment: Определять центр можно узнав сначала эту точку в локальных кардинатах спрайта `Transform.InverseTransformPoint`, а затем зная размеры текстуры и `pixelPerUnit` спрайта перевести в нормализованный вид типа `uv` координат `0>1`.

Comment: Могу ли я как-то скопировать текстуру кроме тяжеленного `texture.SetPixels(SpriteRenderer.sprite.texture.GetPixels());` ? UPDATED: Хотя не такой уж он и тяжелый, это я просто принтил каждый пиксель:) Но все же возможно это не оптимальный вариант?

Comment: Тяжелая не `SetPixel`, а `Apply`. Можно сразу весь массив `GetPixels`/`SetPixels`.

Answer (score 0):

Проще сделать себе ритуальное судоку, чем резать меш на осколки в реальном времени (Procedural Destruction). Так ОЧЕНЬ редко делают и только с знанием дела в ААА играх, типа Control от Remedy.

Объект нужно резать заранее. В 3d редакторах есть такие функции, например в [Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xdrz7icUvC4). Пока сфера цела, это самая обычная сфера для экономии. При хите она подменяется на подготовленный чанк ассет и части её статическим элементам в неком радиусе хита даем rigidbody с неким addForce и можно добавить партиклс.

Если нужны осколки которые можно будет ещё раз раскалывать то елементы в радиусе нужно будет каким-нибудь образом групировать c общим rigidbody. А если после раскола грппы, расколотая группа состоит из одного элемента для продолжения ощущения разрушаемости можно тупо заканчивать это дела партиклами и дымкой.

Идея группирования:

Создаешь компонент с полем `[SerializeField ] private List<KeyValue<int ,int>> _graph` в котором будет справочник-граф кусков с `InstanceID(Min), InstanceID(Max)`. Пишуш кастумны редактор, по нажатию кнопки берет список структур с координатами центов и id `<Vector3, int>`, триангулирует и заполняет наш справочник, `EditorUtility.SetDirty(target)` и готово. По этому заранее подготовленному графу можно будет делать грппы из соседних осколков.

Даже так гемороя выше крыши . Удачи, счастливых выходных .

Но проделав это однажды можно будет создавать разрушаемые объекты конвеерно. Ассет из целой модела, чанк осколков с графом связей и набор эффектов частиц под хит, раскол и уничтожения осколка.

Comment: На самом деле мне не нужны осколки, вообще не нужно, чтобы что-то отлетало. Просто сделать такое вдавление в объекте. Ее могут подстрелить с разных сторон и даже несколько раз: как я для всего в блендере прорисую?

Comment: Я добавил картинку, может так будет попонятнее

Answer (score -1):

По поводу вдавливания. Создай список структуры `<(int)MeshVertextIndex, (float)IndentationValue>`. В неком радиусе хита найди все точки меша и модифицируй вдавливание (`IndentationValue`) в зависимости от дальности от эпицентра, можно ещё с применением шума для красоты.

Есть два варианта реализации:

Использовать `BumpMap`. По `uv` координатам наших `MeshVertextIndex` можно генерировать карту бампа. Но бамп слегка устарел.

Написать шейдер. В vert функции модифицировать каждый вертекс по его нормали в обратном направлении как в этом примере [Normal Extrusion with Vertex Modifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html). Передаем в шейдер массив `IndentationValue`, а что бы узнать индекс каждой вершины в шейдере используй [Vertex ID: SV_VertexID](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderSemantics.html).

Comment: И я опять написал не то что ты хоте...  ты вообще хочень 2d, а я все 3d да 3d. Я не знаю че делать в 2d.

Comment: "Я не знаю че делать в 2d." - что ж, неплохая концовка! В любом случае, спасибо за попытку помочь:)

Comment: А фиг там с концовкой.